# Return single value from ARRAY of STRUCTS based on maximum value

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table where for each item I have an array of STRUCTS with a list of options for label text and associated colour. Each of these options comes with a "ranking" to indicate priority. The table looks something like this:

```
SELECT '1' AS id, [STRUCT('label A' AS label, 'red' AS label_color, 1 AS ranking)] AS label
UNION ALL
SELECT '2' AS id, [STRUCT('label A' AS label, 'red' AS label_color, 1 AS ranking), STRUCT('label B' AS label, 'yellow' AS label_color, 2 AS ranking)] AS label
UNION ALL
SELECT '3' AS id, [STRUCT('label B' AS label, 'blue' AS label_color, 2 AS ranking), STRUCT('label A' AS label, 'blue' AS label_color, 2 AS ranking)] AS label
UNION ALL
SELECT '4' AS id, [STRUCT('label C' AS label, 'red' AS label_color, 1 AS ranking), STRUCT('label B' AS label, 'red' AS label_color, 3 AS ranking)] AS label
UNION ALL
SELECT '5' AS id, [STRUCT('label B' AS label, 'green' AS label_color, 1 AS ranking), STRUCT('label A' AS label, 'red' AS label_color, 2 AS ranking)] AS label
```

[image]

For each ID I need to return a single value. This should be the label with the highest ranking and, in the case where more than one label has the same ranking, then whichever comes first alphabetically.

I've tried a few approaches to this, and can make it work using subqueries within a WHERE statement if I just want the label, but don't know how to pull through both label and colour using this method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rank` and `partition` functions to achieve this.

```sql
WITH labels AS(
SELECT '1' AS id, [STRUCT('label A' AS label, 'red' AS label_color, 1 AS ranking)] AS label
UNION ALL
SELECT '2' AS id, [STRUCT('label A' AS label, 'red' AS label_color, 1 AS ranking), STRUCT('label B' AS label, 'yellow' AS label_color, 2 AS ranking)] AS label
UNION ALL
SELECT '3' AS id, [STRUCT('label B' AS label, 'blue' AS label_color, 2 AS ranking), STRUCT('label A' AS label, 'blue' AS label_color, 2 AS ranking)] AS label
UNION ALL
SELECT '4' AS id, [STRUCT('label C' AS label, 'red' AS label_color, 1 AS ranking), STRUCT('label B' AS label, 'red' AS label_color, 3 AS ranking)] AS label
UNION ALL
SELECT '5' AS id, [STRUCT('label B' AS label, 'green' AS label_color, 1 AS ranking), STRUCT('label A' AS label, 'red' AS label_color, 2 AS ranking)] AS label
),
agg AS
  (
SELECT 
  id,
  a.label,
  a.label_color,
  DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY a.ranking,a.label) lrank
FROM
  labels,labels.label a
)
SELECT * FROM agg WHERE lrank=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [array_agg](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#array_agg):

```
with mytable as (
  SELECT '1' AS id, [STRUCT('label A' AS label, 'red' AS label_color, 1 AS ranking)] AS label UNION ALL
  SELECT '2' AS id, [STRUCT('label A' AS label, 'red' AS label_color, 1 AS ranking), STRUCT('label B' AS label, 'yellow' AS label_color, 2 AS ranking)] AS label UNION ALL
  SELECT '3' AS id, [STRUCT('label B' AS label, 'blue' AS label_color, 2 AS ranking), STRUCT('label A' AS label, 'blue' AS label_color, 2 AS ranking)] AS label UNION ALL
  SELECT '4' AS id, [STRUCT('label C' AS label, 'red' AS label_color, 1 AS ranking), STRUCT('label B' AS label, 'red' AS label_color, 3 AS ranking)] AS label UNION ALL
  SELECT '5' AS id, [STRUCT('label B' AS label, 'green' AS label_color, 1 AS ranking), STRUCT('label A' AS label, 'red' AS label_color, 2 AS ranking)] AS label
)
select id, array_agg(lbl order by lbl.ranking limit 1)[OFFSET(0)].*
from mytable, unnest(label) as lbl
group by id
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the rankings were ordered, you could simply use an array function:

```
select l.id,
       l.label[ordinal(array_length(l.label))]
from labels l;
```

This is not the case in your data.  I *strongly* recommend a correlated subquery:

```
select l.id,
       (select lab
        from unnest(l.label) lab
        order by lab.ranking desc, lab.label
        limit 1
       ) label
from labels l;
```

A correlated subquery avoids `row_number()` or aggregation over the entire data set.  This is a big performance win on a larger data set.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below

```
select l.id,
  (select t from l.label t
   order by ranking, label
   limit 1
  ).* 
from labels l
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]